# Cant figure out why app is not deploying to heroku

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am getting an "internal server error" when deploying my nodejs app to Heroku.

The app works perfectly locally.

The log file shows

```
2020-04-12T20:26:19.601451+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=hurley-order-application.herokuapp.com request_id=22f65
505-f13d-4bd6-92d3-acffc4d8192a fwd="86.40.232.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=427 protocol=https

2020-04-12T20:26:19.602462+00:00 app[web.1]: ::ffff:10.14.25.48 - - [12/Apr/2020:20:26:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 148 "-" "Mozilla/5.
0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"

2020-04-12T20:39:02.946265+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to lookup view "404" in views directory "/app/views"

2020-04-12T20:39:02.946266+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)

2020-04-12T20:39:02.946267+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)

2020-04-12T20:39:02.946268+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/server.js:68:9
```

This obviously isn't an issue locally, do i need to change something here?

The error from Heroku doesnt give much info but is:

```
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

.....

-----> Build succeeded!
```

I have routing as follows in server.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//HOME
// Define routes.
app.get('/',
  function(req, res) {
    res.render('404');
  //  res.render('404', { user: req.user });
  });
```

[image: And routing is:]

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "lukepackage",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://git.heroku.com/hurley-order-application.git"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "connect-ensure-login": "^0.1.1",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.1.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.5",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "Hurley Order Application"
}
```

Comment: The deploy log is useless since deployment succeeds: "Build succeeded!". Please replace that with more information from the error message.

Comment: The Heroku log? what about the NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error, do you think that is relevant? I added to some of the error message too

Comment: No, I don't think that's relevant. It's probably just setting a log level.

Comment: Ok great thanks, added to the error log there

Comment: @Chris its coming from line 68 in the code which is where im openig the App, i changed it to direct it to my simple 404 page just to check it works, and still no dice - must be something here though - added error log and code line

Comment: try to rename Views to views ?

Comment: good idea, was hopeful but no luck, same error! tried ./404, /404, 404, 404.ejs no luck

Comment: According to the error, it is trying to find 404 in folder app/views - i dont have a folder called app, is this just a general folder for my applicaiton or could it be the issue?